# Add Applied Coupon Code in Admin New Order Email Template - WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, coupon, email-notifications

Let me clear my question:

- I have downloaded & activated WooCommerce Plugin for E-Commerce Functionality.
- I want to add "Applied coupon code" in Admin New Order Email Template using my custom plugin.

Now:

1. Can you tell me that exact Hook or Function which is actually setting up that New Order Email Template so that i will override it?
2. Can you tell me how to call applied coupon code, so that i will display this in email template?

It would be great, if you help me please.

Answer (score 8):

This can be done using a custom function hooked in woocommerce_email_order_details action hook (for example) that will display in admin emails notifications the used coupons in the order:

```
// The email function hooked that display the text
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_details', 'display_applied_coupons', 10, 4 );
function display_applied_coupons( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {

    // Only for admins and when there at least 1 coupon in the order
    if ( ! $sent_to_admin && count($order->get_items('coupon') ) == 0 ) return;

    foreach( $order->get_items('coupon') as $coupon ){
        $coupon_codes[] = $coupon->get_code();
    }
    // For one coupon
    if( count($coupon_codes) == 1 ){
        $coupon_code = reset($coupon_codes);
        echo '<p>'.__( 'Coupon Used: ').$coupon_code.'<p>';
    } 
    // For multiple coupons
    else {
        $coupon_codes = implode( ', ', $coupon_codes);
        echo '<p>'.__( 'Coupons Used: ').$coupon_codes.'<p>';
    }
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

Tested and works...

Answer (score 0):

This is because `$coupon_codes` is not an array() define it with `$coupon_codes=array();`