# Display used coupons + specific message on WooCommerce order Emails

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, email-notifications, coupon

I'm trying to display used coupons on WooCommerce order emails + add specific messages based on the used coupons.

Displaying coupons is working based on

[Add Applied Coupon Code in Admin New Order Email Template - WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47341961/11987538)

---

I'm trying to expand on it by checking if the string `$coupon_codes` contains specific words/specific coupons, in this case *"grouppurchase"*, and then displaying a message.

It needs to be for `$coupon_codes` as it can (and will be) used with multiple coupons

I managed to make it work with following code

[How do I check if a string contains a specific word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366730/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-contains-a-specific-word)

**The problem is (strpos) it displays the message whenever ANY coupon is used, doesn't matter that is written in the coupon, and I can't figure out why**

I'm following the strpos logic behind this answer

```php
// Display used Coupons on Emails and Add GroupPurchase Warning
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_after_order_table', 'display_applied_coupons', 10, 4 );
function display_applied_coupons( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {

    // Only for admins and when there at least 1 coupon in the order
    if ( ! $sent_to_admin && count($order->get_items('coupon') ) == 0 ) return;

    foreach( $order->get_items('coupon') as $coupon ){
        $coupon_codes[] = $coupon->get_code();
    }

    // For one coupon
    if( count($coupon_codes) == 1 ){
        $coupon_code = reset($coupon_codes);
        echo '<p>'.__( 'Used Coupon: ').$coupon_code.'<p>';
    }

    // For multiple coupons
    else {
        $coupon_codes = implode( ', ', $coupon_codes);
        echo '<p>'.__( 'Used Coupons: ').$coupon_codes.'<p>';
    }

    if (strpos($coupon_codes, 'groupurchase') !== false) {
        echo '<p>' . 'With this coupon you are participating in a group purchase' . '<p>' ;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give it a try this way

```php
// The email function hooked that display the text
function display_applied_coupons( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {

    // Only for admins and when there at least 1 coupon in the order
    if ( ! $sent_to_admin && count($order->get_items('coupon') ) == 0 ) return;

    foreach( $order->get_items('coupon') as $coupon ){
        $coupon_codes[] = $coupon->get_code();
    }

    // For one coupon
    if( count( $coupon_codes ) == 1 ){
        $coupon_code = reset( $coupon_codes );

        // Set variable output
        $output = '<p>' . __( 'Coupon Used: ', 'woocommerce' ) . $coupon_code . '</p>';

        // Extra
        if ( strpos( $coupon_code, 'groupurchase') !== false ) {
            // Append to
            $output .= '<p>' . __('With this coupon you are participating in a group purchase', 'woocommerce') . '</p>';
        }

        // Echo output
        echo $output;
    } else { // For multiple coupons
        // Loop
        foreach ( $coupon_codes as $coupon_code ) {
            // Set variable output
            $output = '<p>' . __( 'Coupon Used: ', 'woocommerce' ) . $coupon_code . '</p>';

            // Extra
            if ( strpos( $coupon_code, 'groupurchase') !== false ) {
                // Append to
                $output .= '<p>' . __('With this coupon you are participating in a group purchase', 'woocommerce') . '</p>';
            }

            // Echo output
            echo $output;       
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_details', 'display_applied_coupons', 10, 4 );
```

Comment: This works 7uc1f3r! 
Thank you very much. I was trying to study the major differences to see if I could comprehend why strpos wasn't working previously,  Was it the main difference that made it work the fact that you set a variable as the Output instead of straight up "echo"ing directly like I was doing? Or were there more corrections? 
Also, what does the 'woocommerce' make in this case?
Thank you very much in advance once again for all your help and advice, I appreciate it very much!!!

Comment: Because in your code `str_pos` is used for one coupon as well as mulitple. When 1 coupon is applied, the result is an `array` and not a `string`. See [this example](https://pasteboard.co/Jb2WPaO.jpg)

Comment: Of course! That makes total sense! Thank you very much for the straightforward explanation, I truly appreciate it