# Get coupon description From WooCommerce order applied coupons

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, email-notifications, coupon

I'm trying to display used coupons on WooCommerce order emails + add THE DESCRIPTION.

Displaying coupons is working based on:
[Add Applied Coupon Code in Admin New Order Email Template - WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47322228/add-applied-coupon-code-in-admin-new-order-email-template-woocommerce/47341961#47341961)

I also tried this:

```
$coupons = $order->get_items( 'coupon' );
  foreach ( $coupons as $item_id => $item ) {
    echo "<span class='coupon-name'><b>".$item['name']."</b></span>";
    $post = get_post( $item_id );
    echo "<p class='coupon-description'>".$post->post_excerpt."</p>";
  }
}
```

But is not working... any idea?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following to get the coupon description from "coupon" order items:

```
// Loop through WC_Order_Item_Coupon Objects
foreach ( $order->get_items( 'coupon' ) as $item ) {
    // Get the WC_Coupon Object
    $coupon = new WC_Coupon($item->get_code());
    
    // Display coupon description
    echo "<p class='coupon-description'>".$coupon->get_description()."</p>";
}
```

Related: [Get coupon data from WooCommerce orders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44977174/get-coupon-data-from-woocommerce-orders/44982015#44982015)